# How do I install Ubuntu on a Compaq Presario v2000?

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on **Compaq Presario v2000** (old laptop). Having Specifications

**1.40 GHz Intel Celeron processor**  ,40 GB HDD, **760 MB RAM**.

All the system requirements for Ubuntu 12.04 are met with the laptop.  I downloaded the OS ISO image and created a Bootable Cd, after i turn the laptop on it boots from the cd fine, when i click on install it starts to install then a minute or two after that the **dots** below the word Ubuntu are all orange and nothing is happening.  It just hangs there.  Anyone got an answer for me?  All help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your laptop brand and model?

Comment: edit your question to include exactly what kind of laptop you are using.  Also are you trying to install as a dual boot or as the only OS?

Comment: I am trying to install as the only os.  Im installing on a compaq presario v2000, 40 gig hdd, 760MB RAM, 1.40 GHz Intel Celeron processor Windows Xp SP3 is the current os.  I know this is an ooollddd laptop.  It's my moms and she used her friends laptop that has ubuntu on it and now she wants it on hers.

Comment: Your system may not support PAE, try Xubuntu or Lubuntu. [more info](http://askubuntu.com/a/158619/58612)

Comment: Are you sure about ram ,  this model seems to come with 256 MB or 512 MB ram ,or you may want to post the Exact Specs of system.

Comment: Yes Im sure about the ram. I'll look into Lubuntu also.

Answer (score 1):

- Maybe try another flavour of Ubuntu that is more suited for low specs computers?

I think that **Lubuntu** would be the best option, because Ubuntu 12.04 will be extremely slow on the laptop you described. Lubuntu uses LXDE, a lightweight desktop environment that won't need as much memory as Unity.

I know this is not exactly the answer you are looking for, but your problem might actually disappear in Lubuntu's install process.

[Official Lubuntu website](http://lubuntu.net/)

- Did you try [checking your install CD for errors](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck)?
- If you can't fix that and you really want to get Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity, you might want to try the [alternate install CD](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/releases.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/).